# On Unix server: unable to parse currency symbol(£,€) from json to .csv file

Tags: csv, unix, bcp

Below is my java code

```
public Test parseTest(String test) {
            Testresult = null;
            try {
                result = gson.fromJson(test, Test.class);
                if (CAT.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    CAT.debug(result);
                }
            } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
                CAT.warn(e.getMessage() + "\nCan't parse\n" + test);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

To parse Json I am using below jar

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.2</version>
            </dependency>
```

Below is my JSON:

```
Test": [
      {
        "A": "X;DOS533",
        "B": "MCA TEST EUR221.5BN2199AR2019",
        "C": null,
        "D": "AA BB US1.5N",
        "E": "€1.5M Test LN BNK €100M 12M",
        "Ccy": "EUR",
        "TypeCode": "HML  "
      }
```

And below is the row from .csv file generated in unix box.

```
4243842|Test:ABC|Active||6||FFTYIAIT||Internal|X;DOAS5KT|FCA Test EUR221.5BN2199AR2019|?1.51N Test LN RTM ?100M 12M|TCL|
```

Here € sign get replace with ?(question mark).

Same issue I face while converting pound (£) from .csv to .bcp file.

Comment: Looks like a codepage issue

Comment: while executing program locally on windows its working fine.. but not on server

Comment: Windows uses CP1250. Linux normally UTF-8 or ISO-8859. JAVA internal UTF-8

Comment: I see no Java code in your question.  How does this relate to Java?

Comment: will remove java tag.

Comment: You'll need to show your code; without that, nobody is able to help.

Comment: @TobySpeight i have added the java code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried passing streams of bytes instead of String and it works.

Below is the updated code

```
public Test parseTest(String test) {
            Testresult = null;
            try {
               result = gson.fromJson(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(test.getBytes("UTF-8"))), Test.class);
                if (CAT.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    CAT.debug(result);
                }
            } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
                CAT.warn(e.getMessage() + "\nCan't parse\n" + test);
            }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
            return result;
        }
```